# Trying to load CSV file for nfl_elo; argument "dat" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, tidyverse

I can't figure out what it's asking for when it says `dat`.  I have been trying to get the data from project[538]'s website to download. I couldn't get it to download directly fro.m the site, so I downloaded it as

```
nfl_eloRAW <- read_csv("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/nfl-api/nfl_elo.csv")
```

I then applied it to the recommended download format in the 'FiveThirtyEight' package.

```
> nfl_elo <- read_csv((nfl_eloRAW), clean_names(), mutate( team1 = 
as.factor(team1), team2 = as.factor(team2), neutral = ifelse(neutral == 1, 
TRUE, FALSE)), is.data.frame(dat))
Error in is.data.frame(dat) : argument "dat" is missing, with no default
```

When I do it with the data frame directly written as:

```
library(tidyverse) library(janitor) 
nfl_elo <- read_csv("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/nfl-api/nfl_elo.csv") 
clean_names() mutate( team1 = as.factor(team1), team2 = as.factor(team2), 
neutral = ifelse(neutral == 1, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I get error:

> unexpected item in nfl_elo: "clean_names()"

I have tidyverse on and so it should be working. I'm still new so any advice is great. I figure the error in dat may mean data, the data did upload in my global environment. 
I could download the file into excel and import the dataset and maybe avoid a few of these issues trying to format, but I like that if it's being uploaded from a direct patch on the website, it will be updated after every game.

Comment: Haven't you missed pipe (`%>%`) between functions?

Comment: I have tried placing those in back on the original writing -the one provided by fivethirtyeight, where would I need to plave the pipe functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey welcome to stackoverflow, you are just missing the `%>%` pipe operator joining your functions together. Also, I would suggest you indent your code so it's more readable.

I ran the code below to get the following output

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor) 

nfl_elo <- read_csv("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/nfl-api/nfl_elo.csv") %>% 
  clean_names() %>%
  mutate(
    team1 = as.factor(team1), 
    team2 = as.factor(team2),
    neutral = ifelse(neutral == 1, TRUE, FALSE)
  )

nfl_elo

# A tibble: 16,274 x 14
         date season neutral playoff  team1  team2 elo1_pre elo2_pre elo_prob1 elo_prob2 elo1_post elo2_post score1
       <date>  <int>   <lgl>   <chr> <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <int>
 1 1920-09-26   1920   FALSE    <NA>    RII    STP 1503.947 1300.000 0.8246512 0.1753488  1516.108  1287.838     48
 2 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    BFF    WBU 1478.004 1300.000 0.8020003 0.1979997  1489.757  1288.247     32
 3 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    CBD    PTQ 1504.688 1300.000 0.8252672 0.1747328  1516.803  1287.885     48
 4 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    CHI    MUT 1368.333 1300.000 0.6829856 0.3170144  1386.533  1281.800     20
 5 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    RII    MUN 1516.108 1478.004 0.6441711 0.3558289  1542.135  1451.977     45
 6 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    DAY    COL 1493.002 1504.908 0.5758191 0.4241809  1515.434  1482.475     14
 7 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    RCH    ABU 1503.420 1300.000 0.8242121 0.1757879  1510.934  1292.486     10
 8 1920-10-03   1920   FALSE    <NA>    AKR    WHE 1503.420 1300.000 0.8242121 0.1757879  1515.278  1288.142     43
 9 1920-10-10   1920   FALSE    <NA>    CBD    TLM 1516.803 1300.000 0.8350967 0.1649033  1527.799  1289.004     42
10 1920-10-10   1920   FALSE    <NA>    CHI    KEW 1386.533 1300.000 0.7052228 0.2947772  1402.774  1283.760     25
# ... with 16,264 more rows, and 1 more variables: score2 <int>
```